# Posterior distribution of two normal samples

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, posterior

I have a task to find the posterior distribution $θ|(x,y)$ of two random samples $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\sim N(θ,σ_1^2)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\sim N(θ,σ_2^2)$.
The prior I've got is $θ\sim N(μ_0,σ_0^2)$.
I've thought that I actually want to find the difference between these two or a multi normal, but this isn't true.
Do you have any ideas cause I'm stacked!
Thanks in advance

Comment: A good start is to state the mathematical expression what you want to calculate. Guidance on the posterior distribution can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)